# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')' 2

Tags: c#

This line is causing an error in my project:

```
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext")));
```

Error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')'

I have read through a bunch of similar problems online and I cannot find a change that works. It seems that the parameter inside `UseSqlServer()` is returning null. This leads me to believe that I have a configuration mistake.

Here is my code for my Startup and json files:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ContosoUniversity.Data;

namespace ContosoUniversity
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(***;Database=***;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a `SchoolContext` connection defined in your configuration, only `DefaultConnection`

Comment: You are trying to get a connection string called `SchoolContext` but you only have one in the config called `DefaultConnection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get a connection string called `SchoolContext` but you only have one in the config called `DefaultConnection`. So either fix your code:

```
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Or fix your config:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SchoolContext": "Server=....."
  },
  // etc...
```

Comment: @Cole: if this answer helped you solve your problem, please **accept** it and thus reward the person providing the answer. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)